# unable to run start-dfs.sh

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh, localhost

I am unable to run `start-dfs.sh`

```
ubuntu@UBUNTU:~$ start-dfs.sh
14/10/19 19:26:50 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
14/10/19 19:27:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ubuntu@UBUNTU:~$
```

I did the following while installing hadoop:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: It seems you have a firewall preventing remote ssh connection. Have you checked `iptables`?

Comment: Have you modified the default SSH port to something other than port 22?

Answer (score 0):

Does `ssh localhost` work? I guess not. You have to make that work first. You have to have a working combination of public/private key set. For more information, google `passwordless SSH login` or have a look for example here: http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html